# Can I run a 2000W power tool off of a 2000 (4000W peak) modified wave inverter?

Tags: batteries, inverter

Would a 2000W power tool (electrical chainsaw) be able to run off of a 2000W (4000W peak power) **modified wave** inverter connected to a 12V-40AH AGM battery?

Would the motor need more than 2x the rated power when starting? Would a 20% power loss maybe mean the sustained load would be 2400W, hence too much for my selected inverter?

I do expect it to run for just around 10 minutes which would be enough for my need if it does work. (I'm trying to cut the wood from an obsolete structure down to pieces but it's too far from my house to reach it via electrical cord.)

If this wouldn't be feasible, would I probably be able to run something like a 1200W handsaw off of the said system?

Comment: It's always best to talk in terms of voltage - who is to say that a 2 kW inverter doesn't produce 20,000 volts AC?

Comment: It should work, but why all [the trouble](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=battery+powered+chainsaw&t=opera&ia=web)?  Maybe a home improvement store would have one you could rent cheaply for a few hours.

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe the inverter overcurrent will cut out at start-up making it useless.

Comment: What is the starting current? That surge may trip the inverter...

Comment: +1 on starting current. My endeavors with similar things has ended up with a 500 W light bulb in series for inrush limiting and a manual switch to bypass it. Works for a pump but highly unpractical for any often switched on hand tool.

Answer (score 1):

no.

Power tool motors typically want about 10 times their rated power to start.  4000W peak is probably nowhere near enough for a 2000W motor.

If the inverter is capable of enforcing the 4000W limit without shutting down it will probably work, (but saw will be slower to start)

Answer (score -1):

Some basic calculations show that you've got a battery capable of supplying 1.728 MJ of energy. For a 2 kW load, that gives you 14.4 minutes of chainsaw action. However, this assumes that the dc-ac conversion is 100% efficient and that you're actually able to deplete 100% of the battery energy before things shut off. Both of these assumptions are dubious. There's also the issue of whether or not the chainsaw will appreciate the modified sine wave. Some motors may overheat and be damaged running with modified sine wave.

I'd give it a shot. It might work for 10 minutes or so, but if the chainsaw doesn't act or sound 100% normal I'd shut things down pretty quick.